# Excel using text entered in a cell as a sum

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using data in a cell showing as "3/4" and I want to calculate the outcome of that cell as a sum.

E.g

I entered 3/4 and it calculates it as 0.75.

Comment: I am confused, is the problem that excel is representing your sum as 3/4 instead of decimals, or is it that you want 3/4 to be calculated and represented as 0.75?
If it's the latter you want to enter "=3/4" (without the quotes (")) in the cell =)

Comment: I understand that and I am after the latter. However I want it to enter 3/4 in one cell and then the total of the sum 0.75 to display in the cell below.

So I enter 3/4 and it autocalculates it to be 0.75

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue is simply formatting

In a cell, right click and choose Format Cells.

Choose Fraction

Now type in 3/4 and it will remain. You can still perform calculations using this cell reference.

If you just want to see 3/4 as a string, start the text with a `'` (type '3/4) and it will keep it as a string

Or, if you want it become 0.75 then format the cell as Number, type in 3/4 and it will convert to 0.75

Comment: When i change the format it shows the number as 42433

Comment: Yes, try typing it again though @PhilNind, as per my post. Format first, then add the value :)